# Solaris KSSL and a Java web server

Tags: java, jetty, solaris

I'm trying to setup a Solaris KSSL proxy (http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/5575-Less-known-Solaris-Features-kssl.html) as a frontend to a Jetty web server.

I'm able to make KSSL work with Apache web server so that KSSL redirects all incoming SSL traffic from port 443 into an Apache web server listening on port 28080.

However the same configuration does not work when Jetty is listening on port 28080. I verified that the KSSL requests does not even reach Jetty or at least I cannot see them in the access log. Furthermore even if I set a simple Java class which just listens on a server socket, KSSL cannot redirect requests to it.

My question is what are the pre-requisites from a web server in order to be able to get requests from KSSL ?

Best regards,
Lior

Comment: Figured that not specifying the host name resolved the problem. I suspect the host name in the certificate does not match the host name used by ksslcfg.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 very common gotchas when working with kssl.

The first is that the apache listening IP has to be the same
as your ksslcfg command.  So if you have Listen 123.123.123.123:28080 in
the httpd.conf file, then you must use a ksslcfg command with the same IP.
You cannot have it listening on ANY (*) and then list an IP in ksslcfg,
or listen on an IP and leave out the IP on ksslcfg.  Whatever netstat shows
is listening on port 28080 must match the IP used in ksslcfg
(or don't use the IP it is listening on *)

The second is that you must do the operations in this order:

1. ksslcfg
2. restart apache

It doesn't not work if ksslcfg is run without restarting apache afterward.

I've seen many people on the web testing with something like
localhost in their ksslcfg command.  It won't work unless you also
had localhost as the Listen IP in the apache configuration.